# XCUITest pointing to Unit Test target

Tags: xcode, build, xctest, xcuitest

I'm working on adding UITest to my iOS app. I've gone through the steps to create the new UI Test Target, but when I try to even run the sample test, it seems to be pointing to the same target as my Unit Test (which inevitably fails)

Where do I go in Xcode to configure the target for UI tests?
Thanks!

Comment: Were you able to figure out?